# Facebook canvas is suddenly fixed at 800px minimum height even when "Canvas Fixed Width" setting is set to No

Tags: facebook

Up until about 3 days ago my Facebook canvas height would automatically adjust to fit the height of the window.  This was something I was relying on because my app was responsive based on the canvas height.  But now from out of nowhere the iframe_canvas iframe has a min-height property set to 800px.  So if my window drops below that height, the canvas doesn't adjust to match.  Anyone got any idea why this was suddenly added and more importantly how I might go about removing it?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks @WizKid. Done. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/624705084289276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a bug with Facebook and they tell me that this is a known bug that they're currently working to resolve.  In the meantime they've given me a workaround.  All you need to do is set the "Canvas Fixed Height" setting to yes and then give it a value, say 10.  Save that and then set the "Canvas Fixed Height" setting back to no.  Save it again and the problem should be solved.

Comment: Could please give us an url to the bug?